# best way to use context.xml

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, web-applications, database-connection

I have made a web application using tomcat that is connecting to the database and made some transactions on it, but my database oracle admin is complaining of so many connection from it and tells me that it is always cause the database to hang up due to many connection . so my question is what the best context.xml file to use and what modification should i do to mine?

**my context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/applicationName">
    <Resource driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="-1" maxWait="30000" name="name" password="password"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="url"
        username="username" />
    </Context>
```

**my Dao Class**

```
  public Dao(){
}

Context initContext;
Context envContext;
DataSource ds;
Connection conn;
public Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    initContext = new InitialContext();
    envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
    ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("name");
    conn = ds.getConnection();
    if(conn != null){
        return conn;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that the database admin problem? What does mean so many connections?

Comment: @drgPP i have told him so but i want to make it clear from my side, so i dont want to be the mistaken guy

Comment: As the @satheesh kannak wrote, you must ensure you clear the resources (return the connection to pool)  after the user have done his job.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you are closing the connection properly in the code.

Also, you should try

```
finally {
  if(connection!= null) {
    connection.close();
    connection = null;
  }
```

}

Comment: i use  } finally {
            closeConnection(conn);
        }

Comment: @Code Chieftain Also be sure to close ResultSet and PreparedStatement( or Statement) if you use them.

Comment: but i am not having any problem in the configration right?

Comment: @Code Chieftain it seems ok to me, however, ensure with db admin that the db can hold 100 connections per time, maybe he wants to reduce the number of them.

Comment: he said they are 900 lool

Comment: Please refer this link - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5718/when-is-an-application-using-too-many-sessions